# IIS 8.5 500.19 status code with 0x80070038 access share

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, server-message-block, cifs, iis-8.5

We are experiencing an intermittent issue with websites accessing resources/images over CIFS/SMB shares (running on our storage array).  It comes and goes and we are trying to get to the bottom of it.

The error code in the browser is 500.19 with the error code 0x80070038.

I've come across these two locked threads and is seems like the same issue:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1165964.aspx?500+19+error+NetBios+command+limit

http://forums.iis.net/t/1158781.aspx

Is this still applicable in a Windows 2012r2/IIS 8.5 environment?

I've had a look in the registry for MKLM\Services\CurrentControlSet\lanmanworkstation\MaxCmds but cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this post to be helpful such as your case. I hope you find help full too.

Please click this [LINK](https://www.monitis.com/blog/2013/05/16/tuning-windows-2012-file-system-part-1)

Thank You

Comment: a great article on the server side of SMB shares.  Our server is a storage array and we are seeing the issue from the client side (our IIS server).  Unfortunately none of the items in the article relate to clients